# Modularizing code in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**The main question**

I am used to using React with ES6 classes. I am also used to modularizing portions of code into separate functions. I am looking at the following example and trying to figure out how to put the value for onSubmit as a separate function.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
          input.value = ''
        }}
      >
        <input
          ref={node => {
            input = node
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

I have tried something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

function handleSubmit(e){
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
          input.value = ''

}

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input ref={node => {input = node }}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

But then of course it does not work as it does not recognize the input variable. I could pass the input variable to the function, but this does not seem like the right way to do it.

**Question 2:**

I am unfamiliar with what the following piece of code is doing:

`let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {`

Where exactly is it getting dispatch from? Is the value of dispatch being passed into the anonymous function?

**Question 3**

The same with the following code:

`<input ref={node => {input = node }}`

Where is the value of node coming from and why is it being stored into the input variable?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to Question 1**

`AddTodo` is a React stateless functional component (SFC). It is also a function. Within the SFC is defined a variable `input`. In order for the `handleSubmit` callback to be able to make use of `input`, it is necessary that `input` be in the enclosing scope where `handleSubmit` is defined or `input` be passed as an argument to `handleSubmit`.

Thus, the following two implementations achieve the desired behavior:

```
const AddTodo = ({dispatch}) => {
  let input

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    ...
  }

  return (
    ...
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    ...
  )
```

and

```
const handleSubmit = (e, input) => {
  ...
}

const AddTodo = ({dispatch}) => {
  let input

  return (
    ...
      onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e, input)}
    ...
  )
```

I highly recommend reading the following blog post by Kent Dodds, paying particular attention to the use of classes vs function closures.

[Classes, Complexity, and Functional Programming](https://blog.kentcdodds.com/classes-complexity-and-functional-programming-a8dd86903747)

**Answer to Question 2**

The `connect` function from react-redux wraps the `AddTodo` component. The way in which `connect` is being called (with no second argument, or any arguments in this particular case) means `AddTodo` will receive a prop named `dispatch`.

To better understand how react-redux and the `connect` function it provides work, have a look at the documentation:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

**Answer to Question 3**

Refs are built into React. A function passed to the `ref` prop receives the underlying DOM element as an argument. In this case, the function passed to the `ref` prop stores a reference to the DOM element in the variable `input`. This allows the DOM element to be accessed and mutated later by the callback passed to `onSubmit` (i.e. `handleSubmit`). See the React documentation for more details on refs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html